# JPA check if null query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I use database query with `JPA` like that:

```
@Query("SELECT " +
        "new Report(" +
        "sum (r.fraction1)," +
        "sum (r.fraction2)) from Report r")
Report calculateTotalReports();
```

When the database is full, it works fine, but when it is empty, the application crashes. How i can check when table contain rows and then select sum? I tried use `CASE WHEN ... THEN`, but `JPA` is not provide it.

Log of crashes:

> QueryException: could not instantiate class
>   [com.statistic.server.entity.Report] from tuple] with root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source) ~

Comment: Try using `IFNULL` or `COALESCE`

Comment: JPQL clearly does allow CASE statements, http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/query.html#jpql_case  and saying an application crashes is likely down to the application. Posting the actual exception would tell you where it is crashing, because a JPA provider should not "crash" when there is no data.

Comment: If your constructor says `Report(double, double)` try changing it to `Report(Double, Double)` and maybe you'll be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you can use `COALESCE` in this case then it will return 0 if r.fraction1 is null.

```
    @Query("SELECT " +
    "new Report(" +
    "COALESCE(sum(r.fraction1),0)," +
    "COALESCE(sum(r.fraction2),0)) from Report r")
```